# What does it mean if a person tells one else to "Just shuck it"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, american-english

Ok so obviously this is a new thing. Before school let out for the summer I picked my nephew up from school and when he got in the car we started to talk then he told me that another kid told him to "just shuck it" at first I thought he meant "suck it" a vulgar slang but he said "no it's shuck it" I told him I had no clue what that means. Later the same day I tried to look it up but found nothing online to explain what it means when you tell a person to "shuck it" now as of yesterday my nephew and son invited a friend of their's over they were playing a video game and my son told their friend it was his own fault the soldier on the game shot his character then their friend told him "oh shuck it" I heard it and asked what that means and they only told me "it's just something us teens say" but can anyone explain what in the world it means? Is "shuck it" bad grammar?

Comment: I have a 16yo.  I think this is one of the many euphemisms one can use for f- - k.  But your nephew probably doesn't realize it.  Children pick up slang from other children and often say what they hear, without thinking about it.

Comment: So apparently *their friend told him "oh shuck it"*. Looks to me like a euphemism for *"Oh, **fuck** it!"*

Answer (score 1):

I think your first impression was right. As [GDoS](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/px72qla) notes, shuck is used, especially in campus, as an euphemism for suck.

> (US campus) a euph. for suck v.

￼

> - Eble Campus Sl. Nov. 3: shucks – a euphemism for sucks: N.C. State shucks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you it's origin but I know "shuck" means to remove. If you tell someone "shuck the corn" it means remove the outer part. My children explained "shuck it" to me (and in my opinion this is stupid) but it means to remove a statement in other words shut up so shuck it means shut up or shut it. I was surprised when they told me this because I was thinking it would be a dirty term but it's not it is just a lame thing that the teens are saying.